# Detecting USB to RS232 converter when connecting or disconnected

Tags: c#, serial-port, usb, wmi

After much head scratching I managed to find the com port number of the USB to RS232 converters on my system. I have 15 in the present system. **What I now need to do is detect when one is connected or disconnected** so that I can update my table. I can work out how to detect a USB Storage device but the same does not work for USB to RS232 converters. Does anyone have any idea on how I can detect this please?

Here is the code snippet I use to work out the com ports in use by the converters

```
private void btn_tst2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{          
    ManagementObjectSearcher searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher("root\\CIMV2",
    "SELECT * FROM Win32_PnPEntity WHERE ClassGuid=\"{4d36e978-e325-11ce-bfc1-08002be10318}\"");

    foreach (ManagementObject queryObj in searcher.Get())
    {
        rtxbx_output.AppendText(queryObj["Name"].ToString() +"\r");
    }

}
```

Comment: What I need to know is when you plug the usb in not what the port number is. The code above finds me the port number but I am so far unable to know when the USB is plugged in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After much frustration I finally worked out how to achieve what I needed. I post the answer in case it gives a pointer to anyone in the future stuck in the same area. I include comments in the code. What I get at the end is a list of all the Com Ports and this is refreshed when one leaves or joins. The file dbt.h is found on your PC.

To make the code below work just make a solution with a Rich text box and two buttons.

```
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.ComponentModel;
    using System.Data;
    using System.Drawing;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Text;
    using System.Threading.Tasks;
    using System.Windows.Forms;
    using System.Management;    //used to perform WMI queries
    using System.Threading;
    using System.Runtime.InteropServices; // needed for marshalling

    namespace MissionControl
    {
        public partial class Control : Form
        {
            public Control()
            {
                InitializeComponent();
            }

            // WndProc = Window Procedures: Every window has an associated     window procedure — a function that processes all messages sent 
        // or posted to all windows of the class. All aspects of a window's appearance and behavior depend on the window procedure's 
        // response to these messages. see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms632593%28v=vs.85%29.aspx
        protected override void WndProc(ref Message m)
        {
            //you may find these definitions in dbt.h 
            const int WM_DEVICECHANGE = 0x0219; // in dbt.h, BroadcastSpecialMessage constants. 
            const int DBT_DEVICEARRIVAL = 0x8000;  // system detected a device arrived see dbt.h
            const int DBT_DEVICEREMOVECOMPLETE = 0x8004; //system detected a device removal see dbt.h
            const int DBT_DEVTYP_PORT = 0x00000003;  // serial, parallel in dbt.h

            switch (m.Msg)
            {
                case WM_DEVICECHANGE:
                    switch (m.WParam.ToInt32())
                    {
                        case DBT_DEVICEARRIVAL:
                            {
                                // Get the DBT_DEVTYP* as defined in dbt.h
                                // We are looking for DBT_DEVTYP_PORT value = 3 which is Serial port
                                int devTypeA = Marshal.ReadInt32(m.LParam, 4);

                                if (devTypeA == DBT_DEVTYP_PORT)
                                {
                                    rchtxbx_output.SelectedText = string.Empty;
                                    rchtxbx_output.SelectionFont = new Font(rchtxbx_output.SelectionFont, FontStyle.Bold);
                                    rchtxbx_output.SelectionColor = Color.Lime;
                                    rchtxbx_output.AppendText("\rSerial Port Connected\r\rList of Current Ports\r");

                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    // We should never get in here but just in case do somethign rather than fall over
                                    rchtxbx_output.SelectedText = string.Empty;
                                    rchtxbx_output.SelectionFont = new Font(rchtxbx_output.SelectionFont, FontStyle.Bold);
                                    rchtxbx_output.SelectionColor = Color.Red;
                                    rchtxbx_output.AppendText("Non-Serial Port Connected\r");
                                }


                                //To prevent cross threading we will start the function call in its own thread
                                // Create the thread object, passing in GetPortNum
                                //ThreadA is the arrival thread (just connected)
                                Thread ThreadA = new Thread(new ThreadStart(GetPortNum));

                                // Start the thread via a ThreadStart delegate
                                ThreadA.Start();

                            }
                            break;
                        case DBT_DEVICEREMOVECOMPLETE:
                            {
                                // Get the DBT_DEVTYP* as defined in dbt.h
                                // We are looking for DBT_DEVTYP_PORT value = 3 which is Serial port
                                int devTypeD = Marshal.ReadInt32(m.LParam, 4);

                                if (devTypeD == DBT_DEVTYP_PORT)
                                {
                                    rchtxbx_output.SelectedText = string.Empty;
                                    rchtxbx_output.SelectionFont = new Font(rchtxbx_output.SelectionFont, FontStyle.Bold);
                                    rchtxbx_output.SelectionColor = Color.Lime;
                                    rchtxbx_output.AppendText("\rSerial Port Disconnected\r\rList of Current Ports\r");
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    // We should never get in here but just in case do something rather than fall over
                                    rchtxbx_output.SelectedText = string.Empty;
                                    rchtxbx_output.SelectionFont = new Font(rchtxbx_output.SelectionFont, FontStyle.Bold);
                                    rchtxbx_output.SelectionColor = Color.Red;
                                    rchtxbx_output.AppendText("Non-Serial Port Disconneted\r");

                                }

                                //To prevent cross threading we will start the function call in its own thread
                                // Create the thread object, passing in GetPortNum
                                //ThreadD is the departure thread (disconnected) 
                                Thread ThreadD = new Thread(new ThreadStart(GetPortNum));

                                // Start the thread via a ThreadStart delegate
                                ThreadD.Start();
                            }

                            break;
                    }

                    break;
            }
            //we detect the media arrival event 
            base.WndProc(ref m);
        }


        private void btn_close_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.Close();
        }

        private void btn_clr_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            rchtxbx_output.Clear();
        }

        private void GetPortNum()
        {
            //Windows Management Instrumentation (WMI) consists of a set of extensions to the Windows Driver Model that provides an 
            //operating system interface through which instrumented components provide information and notification. 
            // To work out the WMI to use, get the tool https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=8572

            //GUID (or UUID) is an acronym for 'Globally Unique Identifier' (or 'Universally Unique Identifier'). It is a 128-bit 
            //integer number used to identify resources. The term GUID is generally used by developers working with Microsoft 
            //technologies, while UUID is used everywhere else.
            // Get the list of ClassGUID from https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff553426%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

            string comportnum = "";
            int textStart = 0;
            char[] textEnd = { ')' };


            ManagementObjectSearcher searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher("root\\CIMV2",
                    "SELECT * FROM Win32_PnPEntity WHERE ClassGuid=\"{4d36e978-e325-11ce-bfc1-08002be10318}\"");
            foreach (ManagementObject queryObj in searcher.Get())
            {
                comportnum = queryObj["Name"].ToString(); // Get the name of the comm port

                //Format the string to extract the comport number only
                textStart = comportnum.IndexOf("(COM");
                comportnum = comportnum.Remove(0, textStart + 4).TrimEnd(textEnd);

                //To prevent cross threading use Invoke. We are writing to a control created in another thread.
                rchtxbx_output.Invoke(new EventHandler(delegate
                {
                    rchtxbx_output.SelectedText = string.Empty;
                    rchtxbx_output.SelectionFont = new Font(rchtxbx_output.SelectionFont, FontStyle.Bold);
                    rchtxbx_output.SelectionColor = Color.Lime; //set font colour
                    rchtxbx_output.AppendText("Comm Port = " + comportnum + "\r"); //add some text
                    rchtxbx_output.ScrollToCaret(); // move cursor to the end
                }));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make some sort of Thread or Task which queries the array returned from the method `System.IO.Ports.SerialPort.GetPortNames()`: when this array changes, or a new element is added, it means that a new serial port have been connected to the system.

Of course, it will return every serial port on your system, but then you can choose which of them are USB-RS232 converters with your code snippet.

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of `MSSerial_PortName` Please find the snippet.

**Note**: This is not a working code, you have to make changes as per your requirement.

```
private void btn_tst2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {   
// connection to WMI rather than cimv2 namespace       
            ManagementObjectSearcher searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher("root\\WMI",
            "select * from MSSerial_PortName");

            foreach (ManagementObject queryObj in searcher.Get())
            {
               queryObj["Active"]; // status
               queryObj["InstanceName"];  
               queryObj["PortName"]; // port number
            }

        }
```

Comment: Thanks but to make this work I found you have to run as administrator. It then will give the port number just like my original code which will work without being run as administrator. This still gives me the problem of not knowing when the USB to RS232 was inserted or removed which is what I am now trying to do. I can get this if it was a Hard drive, any ideas how to get it if it is a USB to RS232 device?

Comment: Yes you are right, it has to be administrator. But are you not able to get right status by queryObj["Active"];. I would suggest using wbemtest to play with plugging and unplugging and to check status.